# Webdriverwait is not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It seems that my code is correct but not working as expected, Webdriver is not really working in my code. I want the page to be loaded first before going back to the previous page. Below is my code.

```
Browser.clickElement(MenuButton, "XPath", _driver);

        Browser.clickElement(Menus[i], "XPath", _driver);

        for(int j=0; j<1;  j++) //StrategySubLinks.length;
        {
          Browser.clickElement(StrategySubLinks[j], "XPath", _driver);
          //wait for a certain element to be visible before going back to the previous page
          //wait for the footer link
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 5);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"asdfdasf-asdfasdfcookie\"]/p/a[2]")));



          //go back to previous page
          //_driver.navigate().back();
          _driver.navigate().refresh();
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) _driver;
          js.executeScript("window.history.back();");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New release/s of selenium is not stable , I used the old version of selenium which is 2.53 so that the code webdriverwait will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.readyState==\"complete\";"));

void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav, thank you for your answer however it is not working.

Comment: Does your code works properly in your end? I am using eclipse and java as the programming language.